# Can I set android:layout_toLeftOf programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout where I have one `TextView` and this element has its `android:layout_toLeftOf` attribute set to another TextView in this same layout.

Depending on the data received by the app from the server, I need to set the visibility of this one TextView to `GONE` and set the visibility of a `ProgressBar` to `VISIBLE` and then I need the first TextView left align with this Progress bar.

Is this possible to accomplish programmatically?

If not, could you think of a way to tackle the issue?

**EDIT**

Following below advice, this is how my working code looks like:

```
TextProgressBar txtProgressBar = (TextProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarPointsInProgress);
TextView offerName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewOfferName);
android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)offerName.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.progressBarPointsInProgress);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
offerName.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**addRule**

```
RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)ProgressBar.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.youtTextView);
```

Comment: Sweet! I have one doubt though: is the youtTextView being added to the LEFT_OF what?
Should the ProgressBar object be the same I have in my layout?